# QGIS cannot find headers file

Tags: c++, qt, qgis, osgeo

I'm trying to create a custom QGIS desktop application with **Qt 5.9.1**

I have downloaded [OSGeo4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) (x64) geospatial software set and the Github C++ [QGIS samples](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Code-Examples) but I'm facing an error at compile time:

`Cannot open include file: 'qgsmapcanvas.h': No such file or directory`

Actually none of the above headers files are under OSGeo4W folder:

```
#include <qgsapplication.h>
#include <qgsproviderregistry.h>
#include <qgssinglesymbolrenderer.h>
#include <qgsmaplayerregistry.h>
#include <qgsrasterlayer.h>
#include <qgsmapcanvas.h>
```

**But..shouldn't they be in dll libraries (eg qgis_core, qgis_gui ... ) ?**

Anyway, this is my ***.pro** file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = qgis_example4
QT = sql network svg gui core xml
LANGUAGE= C++

INCLUDEPATH +=  "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\include"

LIBS += -L"C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\bin" -lqgis_core -lqgis_gui -lgdal_i -lgeos_c

DEFINES+=CORE_EXPORT=__declspec(dllexport)
DEFINES+=GUI_EXPORT=__declspec(dllexport)

CONFIG += qt gui exceptions stl warn_on debug thread

RESOURCES += resources.qrc

FORMS += mainwindowbase.ui

HEADERS = mainwindow.h

SOURCES = main.cpp \
              mainwindow.cpp
```

PS: there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920574/cannot-find-qgsapplication-h-and-other-header-files) on stackiverflow but I repeated it because the answers given did not give the solution

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**: the needed headers file could be found within the "**qgis-dev**" branch of the project.

> **OSGeo4W** : For users that cannot use OSGeo4W for some reason or just prefer it there is also a weekly snapshot of qgis-dev from OSGeo4W as [standalone installer](http://qgis.org/downloads/weekly/?C=M;O=D)

After the installation you can find header in:

```
C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.99/apps/qgis-dev/include
```

So this is my **.pro** file

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = qgis_example4
QT = sql network svg gui core xml
LANGUAGE= C++


INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.99/include"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.99/apps/qgis-dev/include"

LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.99/apps/qgis-dev/bin" -lqgis_core -lqgis_gui

DEFINES+=CORE_EXPORT=__declspec(dllexport)
DEFINES+=GUI_EXPORT=__declspec(dllexport)

CONFIG += qt gui exceptions stl warn_on debug thread

RESOURCES += resources.qrc

FORMS += mainwindowbase.ui

HEADERS = mainwindow.h

SOURCES = main.cpp \
          mainwindow.cpp
```

Although the files are now present, I still not able to run [QGIS samples](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Code-Examples/tree/master/4_adding_rasters_to_canvas). Maybe I'll move to other sample or I'll do my custom basic application.